# Google Fusion table alternative

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets-api, google-fusion-tables

I am using google fusion table (**which is auto-updated from google sheet**) to generate a map with javascript API but as we know google is turning down the fusion table service in December. so I need to update my javascript code to display the map. My google sheet data is like

```
state, county, group, geometry
AK, Aleutians, 5, '-163.03943,55.45072 -163.03316,55.44276 -163.0298,55.43134 -163.02794,55.42083 -163.03001,55.4128 -163.0345,55.4037 -163.04121,55.39468 -163.04921,55.38195 -163.05912,55.37186 -163.06456,55.36648 -163.07096,55.36133 -163.08164,55.35774 -163.09062,55.35442 -163.10688,55.34883 -163.132,55.34379 -163.13981,55.34315 -163.15394,55.34312 -163.17979,55.34732 -163.19627,55.35078 -163.21495,55.35966 -163.22761,55.36259 -163.23536,55.36611 -163.24705,55.3745 -163.25602,55.38552 -163.26237,55.3942 -163.26747,55.40729 -163.27003,55.41626 -163.27192,55.42385 -163.27089,55.43172 -163.26719,55.4381 -163.26298,55.44367 -163.25908,55.44952 -163.25213,55.45382 -163.25993,55.45905 -163.26713,55.46678 -163.2715,55.47701 -163.27107,55.48489 -163.26793,55.49429 -163.26573,55.49918 -163.26,55.50623 -163.25096,55.51217 -163.24251,55.51772 -163.23229,55.52172 -163.22341,55.52429 -163.2098,55.52701 -163.2018,55.52868 -163.19042,55.53056 -163.17388,55.53212 -163.15661,55.53105 -163.1462,55.52848 -163.13653,55.52502 -163.12725,55.51918 -163.1162,55.5137 -163.10933,55.51029 -163.10137,55.50607 -163.09532,55.50176 -163.09401,55.49707 -163.08416,55.49268 -163.07601,55.48869 -163.06652,55.48041 -163.06056,55.47164 -163.05638,55.46517 -163.05351,55.46293 -163.04729,55.45929 -163.04186,55.45464-162.63769,54.80112 -162.64118,54.79532 -162.64405,54.7891 -162.65375,54.78034 -162.66663,54.77021 -162.6778,54.76272 -162.69236,54.75877 -162.70676,54.75499 -162.72296,54.75315 -162.74018,54.7531 -162.76206,54.75797 -162.78345,54.76528 -162.797,54.77218 -162.80259,54.77582 -162.80741,54.77987 -162.8119,54.78685 -162.81782,54.79944 -162.81901,54.81116 -162.81288,54.82246 -162.80696,54.82952 -162.79569,54.83812 -162.78074,54.84774 -162.76939,54.85336 -162.76339,54.85522 -162.75074,54.8569 -162.7432,54.85785 -162.73747,54.85777 -162.72517,54.85739 -162.71528,54.85668 -162.70222,54.85515 -162.69273,54.85277 -162.68632,54.84995 -162.68269,54.84852 -162.67295,54.84344 -162.66175,54.83557 -162.65021,54.82341 -162.64243,54.81293 -162.63718,54.80479'
```

The Geometry field is in XML format which has multiple coordinates for the polygon. now I want to use this sheet data to generate google Maps. Please let me know how I can achieve this. If I need to change my data format then also let me know.

Comment: I wonder how many identical questions we will see until they shut down FT. Anyway your question is **too broad**. You can use geoJSON, you can parse XML, you can import the XML to a database, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same question.

Maybe this would work:
Open-source maps made for self-hosting
Free OpenStreetMap Vector Tiles:
https://openmaptiles.org/

https://www.quora.com/What-programs-are-similar-to-Google-Fusion-Tables